# Heuristics for optimizing ν-SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Do you know any good heuristics for finding optimal value of ν in case of ν-SVM classification? In this particular problem I have a radial basis kernel, if it helps.

Comment: I posted a reply for almost the same question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9253/nu-svm-parameter-selection?rq=1

Comment: Well, this Q is one year older than that... It obviously is a missed duplicate, but likely too old to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For optimisation, you don't need to perform a grid search; a Nelder-Mead simplex(fminsearch in MATLAB) approach is just as effective and generally much faster, especially if you have a lot of hyper-parameters to tune.  Alternatively you can use gradient descent optimisation - if your implementation doesn't provide gradient information, you can always estimate it by finite differences (as fminunc in MATLAB does).

The Span bound is a good criterion to optimise, as it is fast, but good old cross-validation is hard to beat (but use a continuous statistic such as the squared hinge loss).

HTH

n.b. nu needs to lie in [0,1], however this is not a problem, just re-parameterise as theta = logit(nu), and then optimise theta instead of nu.  You can then use more or less any numerical optimisation technique you like, e.g. Nelder-Mead simplex, gradient descent, local search, genetic algorithms...

Answer (score 1):

There are no general heuristics, you should make a grid search, especially since the value of nu must be between 0-1.