# $\nu$-svm parameter selection

Tags: machine-learning, svm

For the $\nu$-SVM (for both classification and regression cases) the $\nu \in (0;1)$ should be selected.
The LIBSVM guide suggests to use grid search for identifying the optimal value of the $C$ parameter for $C$-SVM, it also recommends to try following values $C = 2^{-5}, 2^{-3}, \dots, 2^{15}$.

So the question is, are there any recommendations for values of the $\nu$ parameter in case of $\nu$-SVMs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than use a grid search, you can just optimise the hyper-parameters using standard numeric optimisation techniques (e.g. gradient descent).  If you don't have estimates of the gradients, you can use the [Nelder-Mead simplex method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder-Mead_simplex_method), which doesn't require gradient information and is vastly more efficient than grid-search methods.  I would use the [logit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) function to map the (0;1) range of $\nu$ onto $(-\infty;+\infty)$ to get an unconstrained optimisation problem.

If you really want to use grid search, then just spacing the evaluation points linearly in the range 0 - 1 should be fine.

Comment: Let me clarify your answer.  So you suggest to use gradient descent like methods for SVM loss function minimization (that depends on $\nu, \alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$), instead of SMO method that optimizes loss function for fixed $\nu$. Right? To use gradient descent, the loss function should be unimodal. So does the loss function unimodal with respect to $\nu$ variable?

Comment: @TheBug, no, the SVM itself is still trained using SMO, but the hyper-parameters ($\nu$ and any kernel parameters) are optimised by gradient descent (or Nelder Mead simplex) minimisation of some suitable model selection criterion (e.g. cross-validation error).  At each step you have to train several SVMs with fixed $\nu$ in order to define the simplex or to compute the gradient (using finite differences if it can't be done analytically).  The cross-validation error is not generally unimodal, but it is normally smooth and such methods work well in practice.

Comment: One more question about this technique. Can be same method applied to find $C$ and $\nu$ for $\nu$-SV regression?

Comment: It should be O.K., I haven't used $\nu$-SVR, but I regularly use these sorts of methods for optimising the hyper-parameters of a wide range of kernel models and Gaussian processes (both regression and classification).  As long as you apply a suitable transformation to get an unconstrained optimisation problem, it seems pretty reliable.

Answer (score 3):

well, actually there is an heuristic to get some meaningful start values, see the [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67118/nips_nu.ps.gz)
"A geometric interpretation of v-SVM" and references therein.

The idea is the following: "v is an upper bound on the fraction of margin errors, a lower bound on the fraction of support vectors, and both quantities approach v asymptotically".
This number cannot exceed the quantity 2*lmin/l, where l is the total number of SVs and lmin is the minimum between the number of positive and negative SVs (labels +/-1).

Notice that this means that for inbalanced problems, you will have to work with lower values of v, so you will tend to overfit data.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\nu$-SVM and $C$-SVM are equivalent (at least for balanced problems). Performing a grid-search over $C$ should be more than sufficient.

Also, generally $C$-SVM is more efficient to solve (note e.g. for $\nu$-SVM in libSVM that the initial starting point will tend to set many non-support vectors to have bound $\alpha_i$, thus loading large parts of the kernel matrix that you may not need).